# Display PDF in <div> tag in my website

Tags: php, pdf, html

I'm developing a PHP MySql website in which pdf will be uploaded by site administrator. Viewers will get a list of all the pdf documents.

What I want is:

1. To open the PDF in my `<div>`.
2. No user should be able to download the PDF by any means.

I tried google doc viewer, it simply converts pdf to images which can be saved easily.
Also it gives `View in Full` option by which one can easily download the pdf.

And ofcourse,

`<div><object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200"></object></div>`

is not working.
Please help..

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iframe to embed a PDF inside a div, though it will rely on them having a PDF-reader plugin enabled on their browser. However, **there is no way to show a PDF to a user in a way that does not let them save it**

In order to read the PDF they HAVE to save a tmp version on their computer in any case, so you simply cannot prevent them from having a copy if they want.

[There are a variety of ways to make it more difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630139/is-there-any-way-to-keep-users-from-saving-documents-locally), but that's it. Tieson's solution, which draws the PDF to an HTML5 canvass makes it difficult to get the original PDF for non-technical users, but it only took about 2 minutes for me to find the PDF source and download the original (i.e. http://hazaar.funkynerd.com/pdfdoc/get?file=acr5smallpdf_80327_7.pdf). There are other, similar approaches using java [or flash](http://www.artfans.info/open-pdf-file-from-flash-using-fscommand/) that don't actually show the PDF, but rather a rendering of the PDF by a third-party plugin, which will make it even more difficult, but even then the user could re-create the PDF using third-party tools or just simple screenshots, etc.

Comment: ohh.. So there's no way we can do this.. thats sad

Comment: Loading pdf on the fly in flash would also be a great help indeed

Comment: I've added a link to a [simple tutorial for the flash solution](http://www.artfans.info/open-pdf-file-from-flash-using-fscommand/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not really 100% reliable/stable, but there is a jQuery plugin for Mozilla's experimental PDF.js at http://dev.funkynerd.com/projects/jquery-pdfdoc